# How to convert an array to a string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

For an array like the one below; what would be the best way to get the array values and store them as a comma-separated string?

```
Array ( [0] => 33160,
        [1] => 33280,
        [2] => 33180,
        [3] => 33163,
        [4] => 33181,
        [5] => 33164,
        [6] => 33162,
        [7] => 33179,
        [8] => 33154,
        [9] => 33008,
        [10] => 33009,
        [11] => 33161,
        [12] => 33261,
        [13] => 33269,
        [14] => 33169,
        [15] => 33022,
        [16] => 33141,
        [17] => 33168,
        [18] => 33020,
        [19] => 33023,
        [20] => 33019,
        [21] => 33153,
        [22] => 33238,
        [23] => 33138,
        [24] => 33167,
        [25] => 33082,)
```

Comment: Why does this need to be a string?  How would you like this string to be formatted?  What are you doing with it?  More details would be nice.

Comment: just comma separated zipcodes like so 33160,33280,33180 etc...

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I would turn it into CSV form, like so:

```
$string_version = implode(',', $original_array)
```

You can turn it back by doing:

```
$destination_array = explode(',', $string_version)
```

Comment: CSV is the format user74283's specifies in his comment on his question.

Comment: If you want it human readable, you may want to add a space after the comma. `', '`

Comment: This works, unless you have an array inside your array, at which point you get "Array" as a string.

Comment: @Jacksonkr: Yes. For that, you would need to make some sort of recursive functionality. That would be a different question, though. Feel free to post a new question if you need that. :)

Answer (score 47):

I would turn it into a json object, with the added benefit of keeping the keys if you are using an associative array:

```
$stringRepresentation= json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Also, this will be more useful than `implode` if you are working with nested arrays.

Answer (score 11):

Using [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), you can turn the array into a string.

```
$str = implode(',', $array); // 33160,33280,33180,...
```

Answer (score 5):

[serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) convert between php objects and a string representation.

Answer (score 3):

```
implode(' ',$array);
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a built-in function [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to assign array values to string.
Use it like this:

```
$str = implode(",", $array);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answer is any better or different than the even older ones, like for instance [gen_Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260631/). Per its [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19196135/revisions) even the syntax was wrong initially. It was only corrected by others in 2019. Why did it get ~4 upvotes?

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `implode` function can be used to convert an array into a string --- it is similar to `join` in other languages.

You can use it like so:

```php
$string_product = implode(',', $array);
```

With an array like `[1, 2, 3]`, this would result in a string like `"1,2,3"`.

Answer (score 0):

[implode](http://us.php.net/implode)?