# AJAX: send various data with a single variable

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following code that sends, with the post method, a series of data to another php page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#min_price').change(function(){  
    var price = $(this).val(); 
    var codehotelstring = (<?php echo $impl_selez_hotel ?>); 
       $("#price_range").text("Product under EUR." + price);  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"/loading-price-range.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data: {price: price, codehotelstring: codehotelstring},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $("#product_loading").fadeIn(500).html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });
```

The script works regularly, but I have the problem that the "codehotelstring" variable sends only the last of a series of data, taken from a mysqli query.
The data string is as follows:

```
"1071bf", "107155", "114c25", "137521", "15baf7", "19d7f9", "10b280", "19f2fa", "110bfb", "1106eb", "1398c4 "," 1071b8 "," 107124 "," 1071c7 "," 19d97b "," 16d78f "," 10727b "," 107127 "," 10aab6 "," 193e62 "," 110bf5 "," 107126 "," 189b95 ", "107357", "10731e", "107061", "114e7a", "19d938", "107078", "1070a2", "1070a3", "107af1", "1070a7", "107311".
```

By executing a `"print_r ($ _POST ['codehotelstring']);"` on the landing page, the result displayed is "107311".

I also tried to perform a foreach for the data obtained with `$ _POST ['codehotelstring']`, but without solving the problem.

Comment: Can you post the php as well

Comment: try `serialize`

Comment: Also, you should use an array and send it as JSON string instead of using regular strings!

Comment: I do not think it's a php problem, because by displaying the html source code of the script, the codes are published correctly.

Comment: try `contentType: 'application/json',` in your case, this may also help

Comment: @Varun. A Json string is very interesting. I did not think about it

Comment: try also `serializeArray()` on the codehotelstring  then add `Datatype:'json'` on the ajax setup

Comment: from where do you get `$impl_selez_hotel` variable can you post that code please

Comment: json would do this like Tiwari mentioned.

Comment: replace round bracket with  box bracket if its round then the variable is assigned the last number so var a= (1,2); a = 2 so it should be a = {1,2} or  [1.2]   (<?php echo $impl_selez_hotel ?>);  should be  [<?php echo $impl_selez_hotel ?>]

Comment: @wilsonrufus I replaced the round with the bracket. The result is the following: Array ( [0] => 1071bf [1] => 107155 [2] => 114c25 [3] => 137521 [4] => 15baf7 [5] => 19d7f9 [6] => 10b280 [7] => 19f2fa [8] => 110bfb [9] => 1106eb [10] => 1398c4 [11] => 1071b8 [12] => 107124 [13] => 1071c7 [14] => 19d97b [15] => 16d78f [16] => 10727b [17] => 107127 [18] => 10aab6 [19] => 193e62 [20] => 110bf5 [21] => 107126 [22] => 189b95 [23] => 107357 [24] => 10731e [25] => 107061 [26] => 114e7a [27] => 19d938 [28] => 107078).  now I should just do a foreach to extract each data individually ... right?

Comment: @IdeaProject yes its an array so foreach should work or if you want it to be same as the initial string refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260590/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1):

In javascript.

```
 var first_name = 'stack'; // you can also use jquery or javascript here to get the value of id;
 var last_name = 'overflow';
 var postForm = { 
                'firstname':first_name ,

                'lastname': last_name

              };

 $.ajax({url:localhost/index.php, 
                       type: "POST",
                       data: postForm, //Forms name

                       error: function (xhr, status)
                                       {
                               //Error message
                                       },
                        success: function(msg)
                         {
                            //response of the server
                              alert(msg);
                         }
                 });
```

In index.php

```
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
echo($firstname.$lastname); //this echo result will be displayed as response from the server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to json encode the `$impl_selez_hotel` before sending it to the server, like this:

```
var codehotelstring = "<?php echo json_encode($impl_selez_hotel); ?>";
```

Then you can json decode server side:

```
$decodedData = json_decode($_POST['codehotelstring']);
```

Note that this is not tested code, i am just writing by memory :)